# Phaser - Moving sprites with another sprite

Tags: phaser-framework

I am starting with phaser and I want to make a character and some rocks, I want these rocks to be moved by this character.

My intention is that when the character is touching the rock he can't go trough it and he can move it in the direction he is pointing.

Any idea how can I do it? Tell me some functions or Objects to use.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the physics system used, You will need to use a collision function. In Arcade physics this code would be in your update function:

```
game.physics.arcade.collide(player, rock, pushRock);
```

Then you would declare a function pushRock, that will handle what happens when your player collides/touches the rock. In your case, push the rock in the direction that the player is facing.

I recommend looking [here](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/7947-in-arcade-mode-pushing-objects-around-the-level/) and searching around, where you might find some more help or examples.